# JPARepository is not saving to DB

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc

Long story, but I had to redesign an application this weekend. From a spring boot app to a spring batch app. The process was always a batch process, but I tried to make this batch engine and it got way too complex and i had to stop what I was doing. I'm sure we've all been there. Anyway everything is working fine!! Except for one piece of code that I tried to keep the original piece of code for. I'm trying to use a JPARepository save method and it's not working!! I am able to call the save method, I feel like the Repo is instantiated because I'm not getting a null pointer exception. In fact, I'm not getting any exceptions thrown. I am just not seeing anything in the DB. And I know this code has worked because I had it running in the previous design. Anyway here are my classes...

Data object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="PAYEE_QUAL_LS")
public class PayeeList {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PayeeListPK payeeListPK = new PayeeListPK();
    @Column(name = "PAYEE_QUAL_CD")
    private String payeeQualCode;
    @Column(name = "ETL_TS")
    private Timestamp etlTimestamp;
}
```

Primary key data class...

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class PayeeListPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PAYEE_NM")
    private String payeeName;
    @Column(name = "BAT_PROC_DT")
    private Date batchProcDate;
}
```

Repo class...

```
@Repository
public interface PayeeListRepo extends JpaRepository<PayeeList,String> {}
```

My Service class...

```
public class OracleService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleService.class);

    @Autowired
    PayeeListRepo payeeListRepo;

    public void loadToPayeeListTable(PayeeList payeeList) {
        payeeListRepo.save(payeeList);
    }
```

I have an implementation of Tasklet which I am calling from my batch Step...

```
public class PayeeListTableLoad implements Tasklet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PayeeListTableLoad.class);

    private java.sql.Date procDt;
    private String inputFile;
    private Timestamp time;
    private int safeRecordCount = 0;
    private int blockRecordCount = 0;
    private int safeRejectRecordCount = 0;
    private int blockRejectRecordCount = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> rejectRecordList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    OracleService oracleService;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        java.util.Date parsed = format.parse(System.getenv("procDt"));
        procDt = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
        inputFile = Constants.filePath;
        time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        logger.info("Running data quality checks on input file and loading to Oracle");

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (dataQuality(line)) {
                    PayeeList payeeList = buildPayeeListObject(line);
                    oracleService.loadToPayeeListTable(payeeList);
                    logger.info("Record loaded: " + line);
                } else {
                    rejectRecordList.add(line);
                    try {
                        if (line.split("\\|")[1].equals("B")) {
                            blockRejectRecordCount++;
                        } else if (line.split("\\|")[1].equals("S")) {
                            safeRejectRecordCount++;
                        }
                        logger.info("Record rejected: " + line);
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.info("Safe record count is: " + safeRecordCount);
        logger.info("Block record count is: " + blockRecordCount);
        logger.info("Rejected records are: " + rejectRecordList);

        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
        sendEmail.sendEmail(Constants.aegisCheckInclearingRecipient,Constants.aegisCheckInclearingSender,Constants.payeeListFileSuccessEmailSubject,Constants.payeeListFileSuccessEmailBodyBuilder(safeRecordCount,blockRecordCount,safeRejectRecordCount,blockRejectRecordCount,rejectRecordList));

        logger.info("Successfully loaded to Oracle and sent out Email to stakeholders");

        return null;
    }
```

In my batch configuration....

```
    @Bean
    public OracleService oracleService() { return new OracleService(); }

    @Bean
    public PayeeListTableLoad payeeListTableLoad() {
        return new PayeeListTableLoad();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step payeeListLoadStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("payeeListLoadStep")
                .tasklet(payeeListTableLoad())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job loadPositivePayFile(NotificationListener listener, Step positivePayLoadStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("loadPositivePayFile")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(positivePayDataQualityStep())
                .next(initialCleanUpStep())
                .next(positivePayLoadStep)
                .next(metadataTableLoadStep())
                .next(cleanUpGOSStep())
                .build();
    }
```

Ultimately our step is running an implementation of Tasklet, we are Autowiring out OracleService class, and then that is being called and is then calling the Repo method. I am getting to the Oracle Service class method and I am calling the save method of my Autowired Repository but again nothing is happening!!

**EDIT!!!**

I have figured out another way to do it and that is with EntityManager and using the persist and flush methods. Below is now my loadToPayeeListTable method in my Oracle Service class...

```
    public void loadToPayeeListTable(PayeeList payeeList) throws ParseException {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.persist(payeeList);
        entityManager.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

Comment: `logger.info("Record loaded: " + line);` - is this being printed?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes that is being printed!

Comment: Usually I would ask whether you are looking at the correct DB

Comment: @ScaryWombat there are other Steps in the batch for other Jobs that are using JdbcBatchItemWriter and it's writing fine. This is all being set up through a Datasource that has it's configuration in a OracleConfiguration class

Comment: Why a tasklet and not a reader/processor/writer? Seems you are still not fully embracing Spring Batch. That being said your service doesn't look transactional, no transaction no saving. However 1 transaction for each save isn't performant so you need chunks of x size (x you need to determine yourself). Hence you are probably better of using a reader/writer which supports all of this out-of-the-box.

Comment: @M.Deinum i need the ability to run data qualityt checks on each record, if it does not pass data quality, then store that record in a list and move on to the next record. this functionality was already coded in spring boot so I'm trying to reuse the logic

Comment: This has nothing to do with being coded in Spring Boot or not, it is about using Spring Batch properly, also which large files you will run into memory issues as you are keeping everything in-memory. Nonetheless there is nothing transaction related in your code or service, no transaction nothing persisted in the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum also this file will be like 500 records long. It's very small. No need for chunks

Comment: Nonetheless you still need transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum then why did this code work with my spring boot application? I was calling this oracle service class from a Controller annotated class

Comment: I figured it out. I removed the whole JPA repository and am using a entitymanager with the persist and flush method

Comment: A flush isn't a transaction either. You need a transactional boundary. Could be that your controller was transactional or due to the use of a open-session-in-view pattern that it worked.

Comment: did you ever find the root cause of this problem? I'm facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a try to passe the repository with a Spring Test? I have never met this problem, but I am not sure about the DB type. Is it Mysql, Oracle? Because I never used it with  @EmbeddedId.
IF you passed the unit test, you ought to check your service logic with debugging. Opposite, you ought to passe the test first.

Comment: FWIW This is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Change your jpa repository to

```
@Repository
public interface PayeeListRepo extends JpaRepository<PayeeList, PayeeListPK>
```

Comment: Adding an annotation won't help.

Comment: @M.Deinum The annotation is with the existing code.

Comment: An annotation on an interface doesn't do anything and in this case it doesn't even add anything as Spring Data has a different way of detecting repositories.